# CI3 Advanced Search Filter with Query Strings

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement, search, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to implement an advanced search into my Codeigniter 3 site.

The current search functionality works fine (*search all records*).

I have a simple HTML form with one input (`searchTerm`), this sends a query string `q=`. My basic search syntax is;

```
$searchTerm  = $this->input->get('q'); 
if ($searchTerm) { 
    $this->db->from('records');
    $this->db->where('column1', $searchTerm); 
    $this->db->where('column2', $searchTerm);
    $this->db->where('column3', $searchTerm);
    // $this->db->where('etc', $searchTerm);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

There are approximately 20 columns in my database.

I want to add an additional three inputs to my HTML form that will search these database columns;

- collectionId
- startYear
- endYear

Do I need to create a new function for each possible search combination? Users can search for one **or** the other. One **and** the other. Just **one**.

That will be a lot of `if/else` statements? For example;

```
 - if searchTerm is not empty
 - if searchTerm is not empty and startYear is not empty
 - if startYear is empty and endYear is not empty
 - etc
 - etc
```

Perhaps there is a more efficient way of doing this?

I don't want to use any additional libraries or plugins.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could ensure you're posted fields have the same name as your database fields and do something like this:

```
$search_query = $this->input->get(); //assuming your query strings are only search terms 

foreach($search_query as $search){
    $this-db->or_where($search, $search);  //or where, you could also you $this-db->where();  which will produce where and foreach element 
}
return $this-db->get('records')->result();
```

If your query string contains things other than search terms, you can unset them from `$search_query` before continuing to the loop.

Comment: Thanks @Kisaragi Unfortunately my posted fields don't have the same name as my database, it would involve too much work to change them all at this stage :/ Plus, wouldn't the line `$this-db->or_where($search, $search)` produce `OR WHERE searchTerm = searchTerm` ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
$searchTerm  = $this->input->get('q');
$searchTerm1  = $this->input->get('x');
$searchTerm2  = $this->input->get('y');
$searchTerm3  = $this->input->get('z');

if(!empty($searchTerm1)){
    $this->db->where('collectionId', $searchTerm1);
}

if(!empty($searchTerm2)){
    $this->db->where('startYear = "'.$searchTerm2.'"', NULL,FALSE);
}

if(!empty($searchTerm3)){
    $this->db->where('endYear BETWEEN "'.$searchTerm3.'" AND NOW()', NULL,FALSE);
}



if ($searchTerm) { 
    $this->db->from('records');
    $this->db->where('column1', $searchTerm); 
    $this->db->where('column2', $searchTerm);
    $this->db->where('column3', $searchTerm);
    // $this->db->where('etc', $searchTerm);
}

 $query = $this->db->get();
 return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: Could you briefly explain what is happening in the code? Thanks for your answer, it looks promising.

Comment: @TheOrdinaryGeek nothing special there in code. it just concat `WHERE` when any search term is not empty

Answer (score 0):

if you want to automate things here you should use another approach, the most important thing here is to group things

**A real world example**

Controller

```
class So extends CI_Controller
{

    public function so50157398()
    {
        if ($this->input->post())
        {
            $this->load->model('so/So50157398_model');
            $this->So50157398_model->buildSearch($this->input->post('search'));
        }
        $this->load->view('so/so50157398'); 
    }
}
```

View (a simple boilerplate bootstrap template)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Automatic Search Builder</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="search[or_where][email]" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="search[or_where][password]" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputAddress">Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search[where][address]" id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputAddress2">Address 2</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search[where][address2]" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="inputCity">City</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search[where][city]" id="inputCity">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="inputState">State</label>
                <select id="inputState" name="search[where][state]" class="form-control">
                    <option selected>Choose...</option>
                    <option>Option 1</option>
                    <option>Option 2</option>
                    <option>Option 3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label for="inputZip">Zip</label>
                <input type="text" name="search[where][zip]" class="form-control" id="inputZip">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
    </form>
</div>
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Model

```
class So50157398_model extends CI_Model
{
    private $arrAllowedFields = ['email', 'password', 'address', 'address2', 'city', 'state', 'zip'];

    public function buildSearch($arrSearchFields)
    {
        $this->db
            ->select('*')
            ->from('records');
        foreach($arrSearchFields AS $key => $arrFields)
        {
            $this->buildQuery($key, $arrFields);
        }

        echo $this->db->get_compiled_select();
    }

    private function buildQuery($group, $arrFields)
    {
        $this->db->group_start();
        foreach($arrFields AS $key => $value)
        {
            if (in_array($key, $this->arrAllowedFields))    $this->db->$group($key, $value);
        }
        $this->db->group_end();

    }
}
```

as you can see, i've grouped the input fields in different categories (e.g. in this case or_where, where)

If you follow that approach its pretty simple to build up a dynamic search without building redundant code fragements

of course you've to do some fieldchecks - but for that matter you should use the `Form_Validation` Library.